# Tkinter .place becomes a text box and is too small

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing some come tin tkinter and I am trying to use .place to place all the buttons.
When I run the code, it becomes tiny and all the buttons group together [when i run the code, it all groups together and there is a text box that appears behind it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeuth.png)

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import os


def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.title('o')


f1 = tk.Entry(root)
f2 = tk.Entry(root)
s = tk.Entry(root)

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

for frame in (f1, f2, s):
    frame.grid(row=3000, column=2000, sticky='news')


clicks = IntVar()
inc = IntVar()


def increase(event=None):
    inc.set(inc.get() + 1)


def clicked(event=None):
   clicks.set(clicks.get() + inc.get())


#img = PhotoImage(file='Assets\c.png')
#gc = tk.Label(f2,image=img).place(x=10, y=10)

#menu frame
b1 = tk.Button(f1,text='Go to game', fg="dark green", bg="white", command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).place(x=5)
b2 = tk.Button(f1, text='Quit', fg="red", bg="white", command=lambda:quit()).place(x=50, y=-50)
ml = tk.Label(f1, text='Menu', fg="dark green").place(x=20, y=300)

#game frame
gl = tk.Label(f2, text='Game', fg="dark green").place(x=1, y=1)
b3 = tk.Button(f2, text='Return to menu', fg="dark green", bg="white", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).place(x=10, y=1)
b4 = tk.Button(f2, text='Go to the shop', fg="dark green", bg="white", command=lambda:raise_frame(s)).place(x=20, y=1)
ic = tk.Button(f2, text="Increase", command=clicked, fg="dark green", bg="white").place(x=50, y=50)
ca = tk.Label(f2, textvariable=clicks, fg="dark green").place(x=50, y=100)

#shop frame
st = tk.Label(s, text='The shop', fg="dark green").place(x=1, y=1)
s1 = tk.Button(s, text='Return', fg="dark green", bg="white", command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).place(x=10, y=1)
bb1 = tk.Button(s, text="Test (+2 ppc)", command=increase, fg="dark green", bg="white").place(x=1, y=10)
ds = tk.Label(s, textvariable=clicks, fg="dark green").place(x=10, y=10)
mp = tk.Label(s, textvariable=inc, fg="dark green").place(x=50, y=1)

raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you put other widgets inside `Entry` widgets: `f1`, `f2` and `s`? Should they be instances of `tk.Frame()` instead?  Also `x` and `y` options of `.place()` are in pixels.

Comment: I changed entry to Frame, but now there is nothing on the screen when i run the code

Comment: Since you have used `place(...)` to put widgets into those frames, their size will not be adjusted and will be 1x1 by default.  Specify initial size when creating them.  Or use `grid(...)` instead of `place(...)` on those widgets.

Comment: idefined a height and width but it still appers with nothing

Comment: After changing those `tk.Entry` to `tk.Frame` and specify the width and height, for example `width=300, height=200` in those `tk.Frame(...)`, I can see those widgets although they are put very close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your widgets should be inside the main frame:

```py
b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Go to game', fg="dark green", bg="white", command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).place(x=5)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', fg="red", bg="white", command=lambda:quit()).place(x=50, y=-50)
ml = tk.Label(root, text='Menu', fg="dark green").place(x=20, y=300)
gl = tk.Label(root, text='Game', fg="dark green").place(x=1, y=1)
b3 = tk.Button(root, text='Return to menu', fg="dark green", bg="white", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).place(x=10, y=1)
b4 = tk.Button(root, text='Go to the shop', fg="dark green", bg="white", command=lambda:raise_frame(s)).place(x=20, y=1)
ic = tk.Button(root, text="Increase", command=clicked, fg="dark green", bg="white").place(x=50, y=50)
ca = tk.Label(root, textvariable=clicks, fg="dark green").place(x=50, y=100)
st = tk.Label(root, text='The shop', fg="dark green").place(x=1, y=1)
s1 = tk.Button(root, text='Return', fg="dark green", bg="white", command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).place(x=10, y=1)
bb1 = tk.Button(root, text="Test (+2 ppc)", command=increase, fg="dark green", bg="white").place(x=1, y=10)
ds = tk.Label(root, textvariable=clicks, fg="dark green").place(x=10, y=10)
mp = tk.Label(root, textvariable=inc, fg="dark green").place(x=50, y=1)
```

Though this still leaves your widgets very close together, so you should consider changing their coordinates. Note that the higher the `y` value, the lower the widget is located.

Comment: Why should those widgets be put inside main frame? OP wants to switch frame when `Go to game` button or `Return to menu` button or `Return` button is clicked.  Your solution will lose such feature.